# Illegal mix of collations for operation ' IN ', While using LINQ Lambda with contains clause

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

I am having `Linq` query that fetch city names as keyValue pair, Refer below code

```
 public List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> GetCityKeyValuesByNames(List<string> cityNames)
        {
           
                var cityList = _cityRepo
                    .GetConditionalQuery(x => cityNames.Contains(x.Name))
                    .Select(x => new { Key = x.Name, Value = x.Id })
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(x.Key, x.Value))
                    .ToList();

                return cityList;                
        }
```

However we getting Eception `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Illegal mix of collations for operation ' IN '`, How I can control the collation in EF Linq query?

Comment: Have you specified a collation in the database and matched it in the EF configuration using the `[MySqlcharset]` attribute? (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-charset.html) I would think the EF provider would manage the strings relative to the collation of the property being compared (Name) but it might glitch if misconfigured. Where searching across string values you might want to consider using a case-insensitive collation for that field, also check that the region for the DB and server are compatible.